# Cucumber (capybara) does not find text on a page when running under Semaphore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, unicode, cucumber, capybara

I have a Rails 3 app and I use cucumber for testing. One of my tests has the following step:

`Then I should see "And now a word from our lawyers..."`

The step is defined like this:

```
Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |text|
  expect(page).to have_content text
end
```

When I run the test locally everything works fine. I am using [Semaphoreapp](https://semaphoreapp.com/) as a CI server. After a recent selenium driver update I get the following error when I run the test in my CI environment:

> expected to find text "And now a word from our lawyers..." in " ��� And now a word from our lawyers... "

I assume this has to do with some Unicode issue on the CI service side. Is there a way to configure cucumber/capybara to use Unicode for matching?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I'm seeing something similar.

Comment: No... As a workaround I changed selector on the page to look for text within specific html

Comment: I think that helped, thanks.  My integration tests are so flaky it's hard to tell for sure, but .. I think that helped :)